# Accessing easily from static function to non static members

Tags: c++

I have `class A` with a static function `S` and it has as a parameter the pointer to an instance of `A`.

```
class A {
   int v;
   int f(int v2) { return v2*2;}
public:
   static int S(A *ptA);
}
```

I want to access to the non static members of `A` so in the definition I can do..

```
int S(A *ptA) {
   return ptA->f(ptA->v);
}
```

But unfortunately `S` is to much complex and `v` is not only one variable...

So the question is: Is there a way to set inside a static function the value of this pointer... something like `this=ptA` or `using ptA as this` or whatever to avoid having to use `ptA->` all the time.

Comment: Why cant you make it a non static member function? (P.S: No you cant set "this ptr" in a static function because its static thats the point)

Comment: Did you encounter a compiler error like: "illegal reference to non-static member 'identifier'" [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2597]

Comment: @Borgleader mmm you say something S(A *ptA) { ptA->nonStaticFunctionWereIDontNeedToWriteAllTheTime_ptA(); }.... Because I have a bad day.... You are absolutely right. Thanks.